# use fingerprint in android 3.0

Tags: android

I would like to allow the users based on his fingerprint.
Is that possible in android.I came to knew that android3.0 has fingerprint integrated.How can i use that in my application.How can i save the data related to fingerprint.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for fingerprint recognition in any version of Android.

Some device manufacturers that have added fingerprint readers to their devices may have SDK add-ons or other ways you can integrate with those readers. You will need to contact those device manufacturers to determine if and how this is possible. For example, I think a Motorola phone or two has a fingerprint reader, and you can reach them at the [MOTODEV forums](http://community.developer.motorola.com/).